# Source files are updated, but CMD does not reflect

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I'm new to docker and am trying to dockerize an app I have. Here is the dockerfile I am using:

```
FROM golang:1.10

WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/myuser/pkg
ADD . .

RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golang/dep/master/install.sh | sh
RUN dep ensure

CMD ["go", "run", "cmd/pkg/main.go"]
```

The issue I am running into is that I will update source files on my local machine with some log statements, rebuild the image, and try running it in a container. However, the CMD (`go run cmd/pkg/main.go`) will not reflect the changes I made.

I looked into the container filesystem and I see that the source files are updated and match what I have locally. But when I run `go run cmd/pkg/main.go` within the container, I don't see the log statements I added.

I've tried using the `--no-cache` option when building the image, but that doesn't seem to help. Is this a problem with the golang image, or my dockerfile setup?

UPDATE: I have found the issue. The issue is related to using `dep` for vendoring. The vendor folder had outdated files for my package because `dep ensure` was pulling them from github instead of locally. I will be moving to go 1.1 which support to go modules to fix this.

Comment: Can you share the actual `docker build` and `docker run` commands you're using?

Comment: Sure: `docker build . —no-cache -t pkg` and `docker run —env-file envfile pkg`

Answer (score 0):

I see several things:

**According to your Dockerfile**

1. Maybe you need a `dep init` before `dep ensure`
2. Probably you need to check if `main.go` path is correct.

**According to docker philosophy**

1. In my humble opinion, you should create an image with `docker build -t <your_image_name> .`, executing that where your Dockerfile is, but without `CMD` line.
2. I would execute your `go run <your main.go>` in your `docker run -d <your_image_name> go run <cmd/pkg/main.go>` or whatever is your command.

If something is wrong, you can check exited containers with `docker ps -a` and furthermore check logs with `docker logs <your_CONTAINER_name/id>`

Other way to check logs is access to the container using bash and execute `go run`  manually:

```
docker run -ti <your_image_name> bash
# go run blablabla
```

Comment: There's no reason to remove the CMD.  It says, by default, actually run the program that you're packaging into a Docker image; but if you need an interactive shell, the syntax you have will work fine.

Comment: Reason is that is easier to debug. When program is stable, in production, you can use CMD without problem, of course, but in development or testing phase I recommend execute CMD/ENTRYPOINT with `docker run`, not in `built` phase.

Comment: I have tried accessing the container and running `go run ...` from the bash shell, but still there were no log statements printed. I looked around inside the file system and the file paths and file contents matched my local $GOPATH